# Angular Using forEach cannot acess $scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to iterate through local storage and add to a model within my controller.

```
angular.forEach(localStorage,function(value,key){
    $scope.cats.push(localStorageService.get(key));
});
```

However when I run this code I get

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'cats' of undefined`

I guess I am struggling to understand the concepts of scope in this.

Comment: I think you need to query localStorage to get the data first using `localStorage.get('her is the key');`

Comment: You are correct in that part of the question is wrong, I have been messing a bit and did'nt change it back.  I have edited the question.  The original problem still persists though $scope is undefined.

Comment: Could you post the whole controller?

Comment: Can you add `$scope.cats = []` before the forEach statement? You need to define it before use it for sure. And you need to pass `$scope` into you controller like `function Ctrl($scope){...}`. Just checking...

Comment: I fixed it using the context parameter.  @sza yes I had defined $scope.cats already and it is there in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it like this:

```
angular.forEach(localStorage,function(value,key){
    this.push(localStorageService.get(key));
},$scope.cats);
```

Not sure if this is correct in the Angular way.

Comment: Yep. In the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach), it says the context is needed:
`angular.forEach(obj, iterator[, context]);`

Comment: The brackets around the `context` parameter indicate that it's supposed to be optional.